# How could I use gulp-requirejs to load/compile only Jquery modules I want?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, gulp, requirejs

I am trying to use gulp to load jquery, but only the modules I am actually using, but something allways break in the process. My gulp task ATM is:

`gulp.task('jqRJ', function() {
    rjs({
        generateSourceMaps: true,
        baseUrl: './static/src/js-modules/vendor/jquery',
        name: 'core',
        out: 'jquery-3.1.1.js',
    })
       .pipe(srcmap.init({loadMaps: true}))
       .pipe(srcmap.write(path.srcmaps))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/src/js-modules/vendor/jquery')); 
});`

I am using the folder/file structure for the jquery as it came from `npm install jquery --save-dev`. requirejs load the main jquery file correctly (the one that `define` the dependencies), but it does not load the other dependencies (like the `core` or the `css` modules).

Any Idea how could I accomplish that?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of the `rjs` call? Looking at the `jquery` install I have here, it seems to me you should have a `src/` at the end of your `baseUrl` because the sources are in a `src/` subdirectory. I have to say I don't see the benefit of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Louis am using the content from `src` already on my `baseUrl` path. I am aiming to load just de JQuery modules I am actually using, and not the whole JQuery pack =)